# multiple excel sheets in R

Tags: r, lapply, purrr, readxl

I have a excel file with 131 sheets, that all contain data in the same format. Each sheet contains data of one station, and is named with that number and name. Here is the example for one sheet for station no. 13:

```
(13) stationName
```

So far I read the sheets one by one, for example

```
data13 <- read_excel("mydata.xlsx", n_max = 65, skip = 1, sheet = 7)
```

In every sheet there's data on 52 variables, that I collect by choosing the required columns.

```
ID111 <- data13[c(1:9)] 
ID112 <- data13[c(1,10:17)]
ID113 <- data13[c(1,18:25)]
ID114 <- data13[c(1,26:33)]
ID115 <- data13[c(1,34:41)]
ID123 <- data13[c(1,42:49)]
ID122 <- data13[c(1,50:57)]
etc.
```

these are then put into a list

```
datasets <- list(ID111, ID112, ID113, ID114, ID115, ID123, ID122) 
names(datasets) <- c(111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 123, 122)
```

and I reshape the data using

```
station13 <- map_dfr(datasets, ~ .x %>%
                       setNames( c("Year", "MS", "UL", "JS", "BF", "FF", "RF", "CL", "FL")) %>%
                       pivot_longer(cols = "MS":"FL",
                                    names_to = "Phase", 
                                    values_to = "DOY"
                       ), .id = 'Species') %>%
  relocate(Species, .after = 'Year')
station13$StationID <- "13"
```

at the very end I will combine all dataframes to have all data from all excel sheets in one file using rbind().

So far I did copy&paste it for every station and change the station number manually. Is there a way to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of reading in each of the 131 sheets manually, you can read all the sheets directly into a list using `lapply` (then do whatever operations you need on the list)

```
library(readxl)
# File path
dataxlsx <- "/FilePath/data_file.xlsx"

# Read in all sheets in excel file to a list
xl_list <- lapply(excel_sheets(dataxlsx), read_excel, path = dataxlsx, n_max = 65, skip = 1)
```

You can rename with

```
names(xl_list) <- excel_sheets(dataxlsx)
```

Comment: Thank you, the reading works with this!
But how can I apply my operations to the whole list? I can subset the station name with the list name, but what do assign it to (instead of station13 in the above example)?

Comment: Happy to help! but each section of what you need should be a posted question - stack overflow discourages questions with multiple asks (in fact, they are often closed for the following reason: “This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.”). If you break this up, you’ll get much faster, better help - good luck!